# Is "right to collect" a phrase that acts as a noun?

Tags: phrases, nouns

Some business folks have asked us to name an "entity" as "Right to Collect." We need entity names to be nouns. To me "Right to Collect" doesn't sound like a noun. What would you best describe this phrase as?

Comment: a noun phrase, composed of head noun "Right" and the infinitive phrase "to collect"

Comment: _Right_ is a noun, _to collect_ is adjective to that. Same as _human rights_. I guess the problem is that _right_ is an _abstract_ idea, contrary to, say, _table_. It is still a noun, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Right" is a noun in this context.  It is used in a fashion similar to "privilege" or "entitlement"

Comment: Yes, "Right" is a noun. I'm interested in the full phrase "Right to Collect"

Comment: Well, in the legal field the *right to collect* is used frequently in debt collection actions.........similar to the *right to collect* information.  The phrase **acts** as a noun and is considered a noun clause.